# Powershell - Adding results together

Tags: powershell

I've been scratching my head on this one. I can't for the life of me add the results in the `Message Count` column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$today = (Get-Date)
$fd = $today.AddDays(-7) | Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 00 -Second 0
Get-MailTrafficReport -Direction Inbound -StartDate $fd -EndDate $today -EventType SpamIPBlock
```

output:

```
Date | Event Type  | Direction | Action | Message Count

1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          4359             
1/21/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          3632             
1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          3692            
1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          4138            
1/24/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          4439            
1/25/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          2956           
1/26/2021 12:00:00 AM SpamIPBlock Inbound          1710
```

Comment: I assume you meant to sum the message count, right? Measure-Object is your friend in this case. `(Get-MailTrafficReport -Direction Inbound -StartDate $fd -EndDate $today -EventType SpamIPBlock | Measure-Object -Property 'Message Count' -Sum ).Sum` should be enough I think.